# Igx-grid Column Visibility Changed event showing wrong value

Tags: angular, hidden, igx-grid

I am trying to code some actions based on a change to column visibility. when executing a *(columnVisibilityChanged)="visibilityChanged($event)"* method and selecting a column to make visible, the $event arguments show a newValue based on the old value.

For example, if I want to make the name field visible (it starts as *[hidden]="true"*), and select the checkbox to make it visible, the newValue in the event arguments still show "*false*".

I would expect that behavior from the *(columnVisibilityChanging)* event, but not *(ColumnVisibilityChanged)*.  The docs say this event is thrown after the change is made.

One last piece of data, when changing back, from visible to hidden, the newValue is showing the previous state.  So at least it's consistent.

My question is what is the best way to determine a column's visibility state?

Thanks,
Ted